# MySQL Union two queries of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I created these 2 queries to get the start and end value:

Start value:

```
SELECT IF(`Order`.action = "Buy", `Order`.transMarketGross, `Order`.transMarketNet) AS startValue
 FROM `Order`
 WHERE agentId = (SELECT id FROM Agent WHERE owner = "Alexander") AND
       `Order`.dateTimeExecuted <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 ORDER BY `Order`.dateTimeExecuted DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

End value:

```
    SELECT IF(`Order`.action = "Buy", `Order`.transMarketGross, `Order`.transMarketNet) AS endValue  
    FROM `Order` 
    WHERE agentId = ( SELECT id  
                      FROM Agent 
                     WHERE owner = "Alexander") 
ORDER BY `Order`.dateTimeExecuted DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But now I want the start and end value in one result row, so I thought I could add `UNION` between the 2 queries:

```
 SELECT IF(`Order`.action = "Buy", `Order`.transMarketGross, `Order`.transMarketNet) AS startValue 
 FROM `Order` 
 WHERE agentId = ( SELECT id 
                   FROM Agent 
                   WHERE owner = "Alexander") AND `Order`.dateTimeExecuted <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
 ORDER BY `Order`.dateTimeExecuted DESC LIMIT 1 
 UNION 
 SELECT IF(`Order`.action = "Buy", `Order`.transMarketGross, `Order`.transMarketNet) AS endValue 
 FROM `Order` WHERE agentId = ( SELECT id 
                                FROM Agent 
                                WHERE owner = "Alexander") 
 ORDER BY `Order`.dateTimeExecuted DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using these queries seperately, they do their job, but I get an error on the total query that this query is not valid. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this? Also if there are any improvements to simplify the query, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one row, you might as well use two subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT (CASE WHEN o.action = 'Buy', o.transMarketGross, o.transMarketNet) AS startValue
        FROM `Order` o JOIN
             Agent a
             ON o.agentId = a.id
        WHERE a.owner = 'Alexander' AND
              o.dateTimeExecuted <= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        ORDER BY o.dateTimeExecuted DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ),
       (SELECT (CASE WHEN o.action = 'Buy', o.transMarketGross, o.transMarketNet) AS startValue
        FROM `Order` o JOIN
             Agent a
             ON o.agentId = a.id
        WHERE a.owner = 'Alexander' 
        ORDER BY o.dateTimeExecuted DESC
        LIMIT 1
       );
```

Note that I made the following changes:

- Added table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.
- Qualified all column references, so the query is unambiguous.
- Replaced the `in` with `JOIN`, which seems to be the intention.
- Replaced double quotes with the SQL standard single quotes for string delimiters.
- Use `CASE` (the standard) rather than the bespoke `IF()` for conditional logic.